# Javascript to redirect based on day and time of week

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get a redirect based on day of week, also would like based on time range if possible. Example from Friday 2pm to Saturday 10pm, Sabbath hours.

Thank you, thank you in advance.

```js
<script>

  function Redirect() {


    var today = new Date();
    var weekday = new Array(7);
    weekday[0] = "Sunday";
    weekday[1] = "Monday";
    weekday[2] = "Tuesday";
    weekday[3] = "Wednesday";
    weekday[4] = "Thursday";
    weekday[5] = "Friday";
    weekday[6] = "Saturday";

    var result = weekday[today.getDay()];

    if (weekday == "Monday") window.location = "b.html"
    if (weekday == "Tuesday") window.location = "b.html"
    if (weekday == "Wednesday") window.location = "b.html"
    if (weekday == "Thursday") window.location = "b.html"
    if (weekday == "Friday") window.location = "a.html"
    if (weekday == "Saturday") window.location = "a.html"
    if (weekday == "Sunday") window.location = "b.html"


  } 
</script>
```

Comment: `weekday` is an array. It should be `result  == "Monday"`.

Comment: I think you want to check if `result == Day of Week`, i.e., `if (result == "Monday")`

Comment: And, looking at that code, it should be `if (result === "Sunday") { window.location = 'b.html'; } else {window.location = 'a.html'; }` But, since you clearly know what day-number corresponds to what day, why are you bothering to convert from the number to text in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

Set a list of rules, for example:

```
const rules = [
    { day: 0, from: 0, to: 20, url: 'https://google.com/' }, // Redirect for Sunday 00:00 - 20:00
    { day: 0, url: 'https://ya.ru/' }, // Redirect for Sunday for any other time
    { day: 5, url: 'https://bing.com/' }, // Redirect for Friday
    { from: 12, to: 13, url: 'https://rambler.ru/' }, // Redirect for all days 12:00 - 13:00
    { url: 'https://duckduckgo.com/' }, // Redirect for all other cases
];
```

Then find the first rule that currently satisfies the conditions:

```
function getRedirectUrl() {
    const now = new Date();
    const today = now.getDay();
    const hours = now.getHours();

    const first = rules.find(item =>
        (item.day === undefined || item.day === today) &&
        ((item.from === undefined || item.from >= hours) && (item.to === undefined || item.to < hours))
    );

    return first.url;
}
```

And then make redirect:

```
window.location.href = getRedirectUrl();
```

**Now all the code**

```html
<script>
    const rules = [
        { day: 0, from: 0, to: 20, url: 'https://google.com/' }, // Redirect for Sunday 00:00 - 20:00
        { day: 0, url: 'https://ya.ru/' }, // Redirect for Sunday for any other time
        { day: 5, url: 'https://bing.com/' }, // Redirect for Friday
        { from: 12, to: 13, url: 'https://rambler.ru/' }, // Redirect for all days 12:00 - 13:00
        { url: 'https://duckduckgo.com/' }, // Redirect for all other cases
    ];

    function getRedirectUrl() {
        const now = new Date();
        const today = now.getDay();
        const hours = now.getHours();

        const first = rules.find(item =>
            (item.day === undefined || item.day === today) &&
            ((item.from === undefined || item.from >= hours) && (item.to === undefined || item.to < hours))
        );

        return first.url;
    }

    function redirect() {
        window.location.href = getRedirectUrl();
    }
</script>
```

Now you can call `redirect()` when you need

Comment: And now you need to explain what problem this solves, what the original problem was, how this addresses it, what you changed and why. That way people can *learn* something from your answer. Unexplained code is only useful to those who can read the code and understand the original problem. Also, since you're adjusting code anyway, why are you using `new Array(7)`,  instead of just creating an Array-literal? And, since you're answering the question, you missed out a rather large part: "*also would like based on time range if possible. Example from Friday 2pm to Saturday 10pm.*"

Comment: I've removed the down-vote, but I don't believe that you're explaining the second code block sufficiently; there is a very good chance that the author of the question doesn't know what arrow functions are, or how they work. Or what the conditions you're assessing are doing (or how). It *is* better, but I'd argue there's more to do.

Comment: I am sorry, I just cannot get it to run. I tried every code validator I could find and cant seem to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

This should be working like this, a little bit modified from the answer given by @Maxim Pyshko:

```
<script>
    const default_url = ‘https://facebook.com’;
    const rules = [
        { day: 0, from: 0, to: 20, url: 'https://google.com/' }, // Redirect for Sunday 00:00 - 20:00
        { day: 0, url: 'https://ya.ru/' }, // Redirect for Sunday for any other time
        { day: 5, url: 'https://bing.com/' }, // Redirect for Friday
        { from: 12, to: 13, url: 'https://rambler.ru/' }, // Redirect for all days 12:00 - 13:00
        { url: 'https://duckduckgo.com/' }, // Redirect for all other cases
    ];

    function getRedirectUrl() {
        const now = new Date();
        const today = now.getDay();
        const hours = now.getHours();

        const first = rules.find(item =>
            (item.day === undefined || item.day === today) && (hours >= item.from && hours<=item.to)
        );

        return first ? first.url : default_url;
    }

    function redirect() {
        window.location.href = getRedirectUrl();
    }
</script>
```

Now you can call redirect() when you need

If current hours are between `from` and `to` then pick the current item URL otherwise return the default URL.

I hope this helps.

Comment: This solution does not take into account rules that are missing from/to hours.
E.g. Rule {day:1, url:'google.com'} will be skipped since it is missing hours.